# How to bind Kendo.MVC DataSource Read in WebApi using Ajax Request on Razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a grid defined like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DtoStuff>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Number);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Date);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Total);    
        })
        .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
        .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
        .Pageable()
        .Filterable(f => f.Extra(false).Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn).AllowUnsort(false))
        .ColumnMenu()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .PageSize(15)
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Number))
            .Read(read => read
                .Url("https://local-api.net/Customer/v1/Stuff/Stuffs")
                )
            .Sort(s => s.Add("Date").Descending())
            .Filter(f => f.Add(a => a.Date).IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)))
    )
)
```

And I would like to add a custom Authorization Token mostly like: http://www.telerik.com/forums/cannot-add-a-custom-http-header

but when I do, the params that being sent are all screwed up and I don't know how to get them properly parsed.

Here is the script that add the Header to the datasource

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer @Session["Authorization"]');
        };
        grid.dataSource.read();
    });
</script>
```

and here the controller in the WebApi
Controller.cs

```
 [HttpPost, Route("Stuffs")]
public IHttpActionResult PostStuffs([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var entities = dboModel.Value)
            {
                var query = entities.Stuff
                    .ProjectToType<DtoStuff>();

                request = request == null ? new DataSourceRequest() : request;

                var result = query.ToDataSourceResult(request);

                return Ok(result);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Request is not Valid");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

### Client Side (CSHTML)

1. Make sure Datasource Read Action does not autobind
2. Set the Datasource to Ajax
3. Set the ServerOperation to true
4. Set the Read action with Type = GET (important)

Should look like :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DtoStuff>()
            .Name("grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Number);
                columns.Bound(c => c.Date)
                columns.Bound(c => c.Total);

            })
            .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
            .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
            .Pageable()
            .Filterable(f => f.Extra(false).Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
            .ColumnMenu()
            .AutoBind(false)
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(true)
                .PageSize(15)
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Number))
                .Read(read => read
                    .Url("https://local-api.net/Customer/v1/Stuff/Stuffs")
                    .Type(HttpVerbs.Get)
                    )
                .Sort(s => s.Add("Date").Descending())
                .Filter(f => f.Add(a => a.Date).IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)))
        )
    )
```

### Client Side (Script)

1. Add the beforeSend anonymous function as listed here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/cannot-add-a-custom-http-header

   ```
    $(function () {
       var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

       grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer @Session["Authorization"]');
           if('@Session["StuffedHeader"]' != '')
           {
               xhr.setRequestHeader('StuffedHeader', '@Session["StuffedHeader"]');
           }
       };
       grid.dataSource.read();
   });
   ```

### Server Side (Controller.cs)

1. Create an Option Request (CORS needs that)
2. Implement the get request using this as request parameter:

> [ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))]
>   DataSourceRequest request

3. Choose where to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
4. Using the [EnableCors("*", "*","*")]
5. Using the response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); in the OptionMethod

   ```
   [RoutePrefix("FluffyThings/v1/Stuff")]

   [EnableCors("*", "*","*")]

   public class StuffController : ApiController
   {

       [HttpGet, Route("Stuffs")]

       public IHttpActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
       {
           return PostStuffs(request);
       }

       [HttpPost, Route("Stuffs")]

       public IHttpActionResult PostStuffs([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               using (var entities = dboModel.Value)
               {
                   var query = entities.stuff.ProjectToType<DtoStuff>();

                   request = request == null ? new DataSourceRequest() : request;

                   var result = query.ToDataSourceResult(request);

                   return Ok(result);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               return BadRequest("Request is not Valid");
           }
       }

       [HttpOptions, Route("Stuffs")]
       public HttpResponseMessage OptionsStuffs()
       {
           HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
           //Use this to allow specific origin to access content
           //response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
           response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
           response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, StuffHeader");

           return response;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: How can the headers be set for other requests, like

 
columns.Bound(p => p.Dataset).Width(180)
            .Filterable(fb => fb.Multi(true).Search(true)
                .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(
                    r => r.Url("http://localhost:5000/references/countries")
                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Get)
                    )));